# How to remove an alien element from R.java?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, r.java-file

I use IDEA's intellisense automatically (`Alt`+`Enter`) as I am so used to know which option it will offer. So this morning I was renaming some XML id (`LinearLayout`'s id) and (probably) somehow generated an entry directly into `R.java` file. Later I wanted to compile the project, but I keep getting error: `<identifier> expected`. The `R.java` looks like this now

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int @+id/linearLayoutMessages=0x7f080012;
    //... other IDs
```

Obviously the torn in the file is the prefix *@+id/*.

I tried removing `R.java` and rebuilding the project, but it did not help. The same error and the same entry keeps regenerating itself. I can solve this (temporarily) by manually removing this entry from `R.java`, but I get this message each time I try to rebuild the project.

Any ideas why this strange entry remains persistent even after deleting `R.java`? The version of IDEA is 11.

Comment: Are you sure you don't accidentally have an id of "@+id/@+id/linearLayoutMessages" in your XML?

Comment: I am not, so I will check up this again. But I doubt as compiler does not complain on illegal name after I manually remove R.java entry letting compiler move forward in compilation

Comment: OH MY GOD! You were right. It's just stood there. Please make a reply so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had "@+id/@+id/linearLayoutMessages" in your XML, you silly goose!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was that I wrote android:id="@+id/52_day_card_image" which is illegal. The solution was android:id="@+id/fiftytwo_day_card_image". Silly me, or silly compiler, your choice

Comment: I think Java does not allow variable names starting with a number.